# socketio-client-ue4 (socket.io Unreal engine 4 plugin) failing to find 'SIOJson'

Tags: socket.io, unreal-engine4

I have installed [socketio-client-ue4](https://github.com/getnamo/socketio-client-ue4) to the plugins file of my project.
I have nodejs installed, I have socket.io installed. I am still getting this error [(Screencap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZAER.png) I have scoured the Github but could not find anything about dependencies.

I am running windows 10 x64
I am running Unreal Engine 4.16.2 (I have also tried 4.16.1)
I have the latest installs (as of the time of this post) of Nodejs and Socket.io as well as the socket.io plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved [here](https://github.com/getnamo/socketio-client-ue4/issues/54), I did not downloaded the pre-compiled version of the plug-in, and thus the code I was trying to run was not compiled.